# Tautological Proof Help

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been having some trouble with proving or disproving tautologies. I am very new to proofs and am hoping I am on the right track. The question asks to show that:

> If ψ → φ is a tautology, then ψ and φ are tautologies.

It also asks to show the converse:

> If ψ and φ are tautologies, then ψ → φ is a tautology.

The questions go on to ask about the other connectives as well, but I think if I could some help on just one I should be able to get the others. I suspect that these are basic proofs, but if anyone could help direct me as to how to get started I would be appreciative.

Comment: If a tautology is what I think it is, I do not see why the first statement need be true.

Comment: If $\psi$ is false (always, let's say), what is the truth value of $\psi\to\varphi$?

Comment: Yes this is propositional calculus, sorry if I was unclear

Comment: Re the 3rd sentence of *your* question: "the question" really asks you to show what follows? Perhaps it actually asks you to prove or disprove it?

Comment: For the first,  $p\longrightarrow p$ is a tautology, but $p$ is not.

Comment: $p\to q$ means $(\neg p)\lor q$. In particular $p\to p$ means $(\neg p)\lor p$ which is law of the excluded middle and is assumed to be a tautology for any $p$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim to know how to do this. Here is my attempt for the second one

> If $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are tautologies, then $\psi\to \varphi$.

Proof: Assume $\psi,\varphi$ are tautologies, and suppose that $\psi\to\varphi$ is not a tautology. Then it is possible to have $\psi$ be true and $\varphi$ false. But this is a contradiction, since $\varphi$ is a tautology. Thus, $\psi\to\varphi$ is a tautology.

---

Alternatively,

Assume $\psi,\varphi$ are tautologies. Then
$$\psi\to\varphi\equiv \neg \psi\lor\varphi.$$
The hypothesis implies that $$\neg \psi\lor\varphi\equiv \neg\psi\lor\psi,$$
which is a tautology.

---

If these are suitable, then I would attempt question 1 in a similar fashion.